# Cocos2d-x supports Multiplatform with One-Source project?

Tags: visual-studio, cocos2d-x, multiplatform

Recently I mentioned on cocos2dx and was confused slightly.

So now I'm going to make a cocos2dx project(i.e. with the Visual Studio 2XXX on Windows).
Then can I make the mobile version(i.e. iOS or Android) from that project?
Is this possible?

I used Unity3d, and it actually supports One project->Multiplatform.
I used cocos2d, and I used to add each library or source for each platform.

So now I think cocos2dx is the expansion of cocos2d, so I must manipulate project for each platform.

Please let me explain about this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read wiki of cocos2D-X.. try this
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Getting_Started_with_Cocos2d-x
Using single command you can create projects for each platform which internally shares same source code. If you are adding your own file ofcourse you have to attach that in project files.

Comment: Can you please let me know the correct and detail url?

Comment: Oh. I see. So I can make any project for any platform. But its only the start point. So if I made the windows project, the build result will run only on Windows, and the same with other platforms. I want to program on Visual Studio(Windows) with cocos2dx, and build that project into various platform results, like as with Unity3D. So anyway it's impossible... Cocos2dx supports only sharing library for some platforms. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically you should create muti project for muti platform , and each project share the same c++ code , but only the code wrote with cocos2dx's api .

and you have to wrote different code for different platform to start the game , which I call it Entry code.

but cocos2dx provides some tools , such as create_project.py , to help you to do with these mess , so we can only concentrated on games it self.

but we still have to compile on each platform  .